# Can I re-attach my EBS while a snapshot is pending?

Tags: amazon-ec2, backup, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snapshot

I have my database backed up to an EBS drive. My current backup method is

1) queue all writes (not important how)

2) kill database process

3) detach + umount ebs volume

4) take snapshot

5) reattach AFTER snapshot is complete

My question is, the snap actually takes a while, can I re-attach my EBS while my EC2 snapshot is in the pending state, or do I risk corruption / data lose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use an EBS volume while a snapshot of that volume is pending (being created).

Writes to the volume will not affect what gets put in the snapshot.  The snapshot will be a point-in-time copy of the EBS volume at the time of the create-snapshot call.

Note, however, that you may find writes to the volume have increased latency as they may be slowed down by the snapshot creation activity.

Answer (score 2):

After the snapshot API call returns, you are safe to resume IO on that volume.

From AWS's [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html) on this:

> You may remount and use your volume while the snapshot status is
>   pending.